# Multicast client keeps leaving group every 5 seconds

Tags: multicast, igmp

I have 2 HP DL360P Gen10 with a Windows 10 VM (IP 10.10.1.1) inside it. It is trying to join a multicast group (228.40.0.227). However, based on the wireshark capture (image below), this client is leaving the multicast group every 5 seconds. I have attempted to upgrade the IGMP from version 2 to version 3 using the method described in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1190375/windows-multicast-using-igmpv3-in-igmpv2-environme, but it did not help.

This is all setup locally & I have checked the following :

- Windows Firewall Disabled
- No IGMP Snooping on Switch
- Client is able to send a ping to the server sending the multicast messages & a static rp has configured the gateway router of this client as rendezvous point, so network seems to be fine.
- My second HP DL360P Gen10 client (IP 10.137.116.1) is able to join its multicast group without immediately leaving. (Both of them are receiving from a different multicast address)
- I have setup unicast routing prior to this, but it is my first time attempting multicast routing. Could someone advise me on how I could further investigate / resolve this issue of my client leaving the multicast group every 5 seconds?

[WS1 - Client keeps leaving group on IGMPv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG2Kp.png)
[WS2 - Client keeps leaving group on IGMPv3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09SZ5.png)
[WS3 - Different client, does not leave group on IGMPv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HuEj.png)

-Edit-
I am using PIM-SM, but I do feel relatively confident that my multicast works because of how simple it is (please, correct me if I am wrong!). Below is how the network is currently running
[Physical layout of network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/126em.png)

Comment: Your multicast group is in the [RESERVED multicast](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml#multicast-addresses-9) range, and you should not use that. You can use anything in the Organization-Local scope (`239.0.0.0/8`). What multicast routing protocol are you using? With an RP, it sounds like PIM SM, but you do not detail that, and that configuration is important to you question.